# How to use Markov's inequality to prove a bound in a Random Walk

Tags: probability, markov-process, random-walk

I'm working on a problem using an biased coin for a random walk where the probability of -1 (left) is 1/3 and +1 (right) is probability is 2/3. If we let $X_t$ be our position after $t$ time steps, then $\mathbb{E} X_t \geq t/3$.

I need to show after $t=9n$ steps, we are at a position which is at least $n$ with a probability of at least $1/4$.

I believe I can use Markov's inequality to prove (possibly by contradiction) that our position $X_t$ is within $n$. I reviewed this: [Markov property in a simple random walk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076200/markov-property-in-a-simple-random-walk).

My work so far (not sure if any of this is correct):

1. Markov's inequality can be written as $P(X \geq a) \leq E(X)/a$.
2. From above, $X$ has an expected value of $t/3$ which gives $P(X \geq a) \leq (t/3)/a$.
3. Substituting $t=9n$ gives: $P(X \geq a) \leq (9n/3)/a \implies P(X \geq a) \leq 3n/a$.

Not sure if I'm on the right track. What are my next steps? Substitute values for $a$?

Comment: I think you're on the wrong track.  First, Markov's inequality requires $X$ to be non-negative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality and second, even if it works, since you are interested in $X \ge n$ you would now substitute $a=n$ which gives $P(X \ge n) \le 3n/n = 3$ which is true but completely useless.  You need some stronger inequality for this (although I dont know which one in this case, perhaps Chebyshev's?)

Comment: I see your point. Thanks.